# compare two folders for non identical files with SymmetricDifference?

Tags: c#, linq

I am comparing two folders for non identical files with symmetric difference and write the length and directory name into a text file...But it is writing like

```
5506       D:\Trial\codegenpath\ramcovm247_portal_765\EDKPLAjaxCodeGen.log
5857       D:\Trial\codegenpath\ramcovm247_portal_765\EDKService.log
3741       D:\Trial\codegenpath\ramcovm247_portal_765\EDKTypes.log
10644      D:\Trial\zippedpath\ramcovm247_portal_765\EDKPLAjaxCodeGen.log
11714      D:\Trial\zippedpath\ramcovm247_portal_765\EDKService.log
7482       D:\Trial\zippedpath\ramcovm247_portal_765\EDKTypes.log
```

but i need to write one after other like this

```
5506       D:\Trial\codegenpath\ramcovm247_portal_765\EDKPLAjaxCodeGen.log
10644      D:\Trial\zippedpath\ramcovm247_portal_765\EDKPLAjaxCodeGen.log
5857       D:\Trial\codegenpath\ramcovm247_portal_765\EDKService.log
11714      D:\Trial\zippedpath\ramcovm247_portal_765\EDKService.log
3741       D:\Trial\codegenpath\ramcovm247_portal_765\EDKTypes.log
7482       D:\Trial\zippedpath\ramcovm247_portal_765\EDKTypes.log
```

Here is my code

```
 var queryList1Only2 = (from file in list1 select file).Except(list2, myFileCompare1);
 var queryList1Only22 = (from file in list2 select file).Except(list1, myFileCompare1);
 var difference = queryList1Only2.ToHashSet();
 difference.SymmetricExceptWith(queryList1Only22);
 foreach (var v in difference )
       {
             dest.WriteLine(v.Length + "       " + v.FullName);

       }
```

and

```
public class FileCompareLength : System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<System.IO.FileInfo>
        {
            public FileCompareLength() { }
            public bool Equals(System.IO.FileInfo f1, System.IO.FileInfo f2)
            {
                return (f1.Length == f2.Length);
            }
            public int GetHashCode(System.IO.FileInfo fi)
            {
                string s = String.Format("{0}", fi.Length);
                return s.GetHashCode();
            }
        }
```

Any suggestion??

Comment: @Bolu:It is writing all files in first path and then all files in second path...what i need is to write a file in path and comparitive file in second path

Comment: that's why I'm asking: can you Sort it into the order you want (by filename) before you list it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546137.aspx